# Confusion regarding the derivation of pressure in Kinetic Theory of Gases

Tags: pressure, time, speed, kinetic-theory

I was studying the derivation of the relation between pressure ($P$) and root mean square speed ($v_{\text {RMS}}$) of an ideal gas from Fundamentals of Physics by Halliday, Resnick, Walker. (The same derivation can be found in Wikipedia page on [kinetic theory of gases](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases) under "Equilibrium properties" section.)

One of the steps in the derivation process bothers me, which is illustrated below:

> When a gas molecule collides with the wall of the container perpendicular to the x axis and bounces off in the opposite direction with the same speed (an elastic collision), the change in momentum is given by:
> $${\Delta p=p_{i,x}-p_{f,x}=p_{i,x}-(-p_{i,x})=2p_{i,x}=2mv_{x}}$$

where p is the momentum, i and f indicate initial and final momentum (before and after collision), x indicates that only the x direction is being considered, and v is the speed of the particle (which is the same before and after the collision).

> The particle impacts one specific side wall once every
> $${\displaystyle \Delta t={\frac {2L}{v_{x}}}}$$
> where L is the distance between opposite walls.

So far no problem, but now:

> ***The force due to this particle is
> $$F={\frac {\Delta p}{\Delta t}}={\frac {mv_{x}^{2}}{L}}$$***

- How/why did they substitute the **time period between two successive collisions** for a given molecule with **time for which the force is applied**?

I might be wrong, but aren't the two things (time period between two successive collision and of the collison) different and hence shouldn't be substituted for one another?

Comment: Why are you typing every equation twice? Could you fix that?

Comment: Short answer: it is an approximation, namely it is implicitly assumed that the force is equally distributed between collisions. It makes sense because one is analyzing a small enough patch of the wall where there won't be many more hits within $\Delta t$

Answer (score 1):

I believe you look at the equations too closely. By taking a step back and thinking about the force we arrive at the following conclusion: The mean force is given by the **product** of

1. the average momentum transferred (to the wall) per collision, $\bar p = 2 m \bar v$, and
2. the average number of collisions (with the wall) per unit time interval. Doing the calculation (see below) we obtain
   $\bar N = \frac{1}{6}n\bar v A$, where $n$ is the density.

Hence, thinking in these terms and using "unit time intervals" your problem disappears and we conclude that
$$
\bar F = \bar N \cdot \bar p
= \frac{1}{6}n\bar v A \cdot 2 m \bar v 
= \frac{1}{3} n A m \bar v^2
$$
The pressure is straight forward, $\bar P= \bar F / A$.

Note that for the proper calculation we have to take into account that the momentum is not directed perpendicular to the wall. Instead, we have to consider a distribution of directions and calculate the mean momentum transfer according to this distribution. In doing so we find that the above stated result remains valid, if we replace $\bar{v}^2 = \langle v \rangle^2$ by $\langle v^2 \rangle$.

**Calculation:**

1. We consider one wall of a 3D box.
2. Let's assume that each particle travels only in one of the six possible direction ($\pm x, \pm y, \pm z$). If we have in total $N$ particles, then on average $N/6$ travel towards the particular wall chosen in step 1.
3. Let's consider the unit time interval $dt$. Within this time interval only those particle which are at distance $ds = v dt$ to the wall are able to reach the wall. Hence, these particle occupy a volume $dV = A ds$.

Putting these three ideas together we conclude that the average number of collisions with the wall is given by $\bar N = \frac{n}{6}(A ds)$, where $n$ is the number density.

Answer (score 1):

The aim of this part of the derivation is not to find the mean force that the molecule exerts on the wall *during a collision*, but the mean force it exerts *over the whole time that the molecule is bouncing back and forth*. That's why we   divide the change in momentum per collision with the wall by the time between collisions with this wall (for example the time interval from mid-collision to mid-collision).

You might think of this graphically. A graph of force exerted on the wall by the molecule would be a series of tall spikes at regular intervals. But we're not interested in the individual spikes. We're interested in the mean force, and this would be a low horizontal line on the graph. The area under this line over a given time interval, $\Delta t$, would be equal to the sum of the areas under the spikes, which would equal the sum of the molecule's momentum changes, $\Sigma \Delta \vec p$, due to collisions with the wall over time $\Delta t$. So the mean force would be $\frac {\Sigma \Delta \vec p}{\Delta t}$.

Answer (score 0):

As you've pointed out, the collision time $t_c$ and time between collisions $t_b$ need not be the same.

Nonetheless, the molecule still bounces back and forth between the walls with a period of $T = t_b + t_c$.

But, what is the average force, $F_{avg}$, experienced by the wall *during the whole time* in general? Even when the molecule isn't touching anything at all? (zero force)

Well, if $F_{col}$ is the average force experienced by the wall *during* a collision, then we can say $$F_{avg} = \frac{F_{col}\times t_c}{t_b + t_c} = \frac{2mv}{T}$$ And if the walls are *perfectly rigid* such that $t_c = 0$ and $T = t_b + t_c = 2L/v$, then we can even write $$F_{avg} = \frac{2mv}{2L/v} = \frac{mv^2}{L} = \frac{2E}{L}$$ And if this $F_{avg}$ is applied over some wall area $A$, then we can also write $$P = \frac{F_{avg}}{A} = \frac{2E}{L\times A} = \frac{2E}{V} \Longleftrightarrow PV = 2E$$ thus deriving the [pressure characteristic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/306318/is-energy-density-and-pressure-fundamentally-the-same-thing) in question.